# Как записать текст в файл через bat без кавычек?

Tags: php, xml, bat, exec

Здравствуйте, есть текст который нужно записать в XML

```
$xml = "<InputSettings> <InputSetting> <Name>id_rk</Name>";
```

Записываю его так

```
$cmd = "cmd /c echo '{$xml}' > 'C:\\file.xml'";
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $cmd);
```

Как избавиться от кавычек, которые добавляются при записи?

Дело в том, что

```
$cmd = "cmd /c echo ".$xml_filtered." > 'C:\\file.xml'";
```

Не работает, а только вот так

```
$cmd = "cmd /c echo '{$xml_filtered}' > 'C:\\file.xml'";
```

А так соответственно идут кавычки) мучаюсь 2 часа уже

Можно ли как-то открыть созданный файл через bat и убрать кавычки в начале и в конце?

И как нормально передать русские символы?

Comment: Похоже, вы не залогинились, когда редактировали вопрос. Рекомендую зарегистрироваться, так будет можно получать уведомления и общаться в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

Варианта два:

**использовать EnableDelayedExpansion**

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var=2"
echo(!var!>> C:\\file.xml
```

**экранировать символы &, \, <, >, ^ и | с помощью ^**

```
echo ^<InputSettings^> ^<InputSetting^> ^<Name^>id_rk^<^/Name^> > C:\\file.xml
```

Во втором случае это будет выглядеть так:

```
$xml = "<InputSettings> <InputSetting> <Name>id_rk</Name>";

$xml_filtered = str_replace(
  ['^', '&', '\', '<', '>', '|'], 
  ['^^', '^&', '^\', '^<', '^>', '^|'], 
  $xml);

$cmd = "cmd /c echo ".$xml_filtered." > 'C:\\file.xml'";
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $cmd);
```

Источник: [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)